# What option is missing or it is invalid?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that inserts some grades for students on a specific course.

There are two tables, grades and courses, I created a view on these tables and I want to create a trigger on that view.

The triggers must do the following:

- If a course exists in course_table, then it should insert only the grade in grades_table;
- If a course does not exist in course_table, then it should insert in both grades_table and course_table specific values.

I write this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_notes_students INSTEAD OF    
INSERT ON view_notes_students    
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN    
    DECLARE temp_var NUMBER(2) := 0;    
    BEGIN    
        SET temp_var = (SELECT count(course_id) FROM course_table WHERE course_table.course_id = :new.course_id);    
        IF temp_var = 1 THEN    
            INTO grades_table(grade_id, course_id, grade_value) VALUES (:new.grade_id,:new.course_id,:new.grade_value);    
        ELSE    
            INSERT INTO course_table(course_id, course_name) VALUES (:new.course_id, :new.course_name);    
            INSERT INTO grades_table(grade_id, course_id, grade_value) VALUES (:new.grade_id,:new.course_id,:new.grade_value);    
    END IF;    
    END;    
END;    
/
```

The trigger is created, but I receive this errors on compilation.

```
4/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Comment: There is no SET statement in PL/SQL. See the manual on how to assign values to variables: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET temp_var = (SELECT count(course_id) FROM course_table WHERE course_table.course_id = :new.course_id);
```

should be

```
SELECT count(course_id) INTO temp_var FROM course_table WHERE course_table.course_id = :new.course_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_notes_students
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON view_notes_students    
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  temp_var NUMBER(2);
BEGIN    
  SELECT count(course_id)
  INTO   temp_var
  FROM   course_table
  WHERE  course_table.course_id = :new.course_id;

  INSERT INTO grades_table(grade_id, course_id, grade_value) VALUES (:new.grade_id,:new.course_id,:new.grade_value);    
  IF temp_var > 0 THEN    
      INSERT INTO course_table(course_id, course_name) VALUES (:new.course_id, :new.course_name);    
  END IF;    
END;    
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Comment: Indeed, this can be another short form of the trigger. 
Thank you!